# Do certain CPUs offer certain advantages for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, cpu

I'm about to buy a new PC that will run Windows 7.

My question:

> Do certain CPUs offer certain advantages for Windows 7?

As a rule of thumb, more expensive CPUs yield better performance and more features; but I'd like to know the marginal benefit of each tier.

For example:

- Do some CPUs support virtualization much better than others?
- Past a certain threshold, will more expensive CPUs support Windows 7 better than others?

  - And if there is such a threshold, what is that threshold?

I'm also very interested in the AMD/Intel dichotomy; so if you could elaborate on that, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [**TR's Windows 7 system guide**](http://techreport.com/articles.x/17787): Recommendations for building the right enthusiast's PCs
   Gives some configurations and suggestions

   - A [Slashdot thread: **Windows 7 On Multicore — How Much Faster?**](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/09/10/21/1234214/Windows-7-On-Multicore-mdash-How-Much-Faster) to slide over;
     could be informative if you can handle some distraction.
   - Lighter reading at InfoWorld: [**How Intel Nehalem processors and Windows 7 work together**](http://www.infoworld.com/d/windows/how-intel-nehalem-processors-and-windows-7-work-together-335)

Comment: Thanks - That first link is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to run a virtualized [XP mode](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2009/05/r2e-microsoft-intel-goof-up-windows-7s-xp-mode.ars) along with Windows 7, make sure you get Intel CPU with VT-x or AMD CPU with AMD-V.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 includes [parallel processing enhancements](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/intel-core-i5,2410-8.html) that utilizes multi-core CPU's. Thus, you will gain solid performance improvements going from a Dual Core to a Quad core to a Core i7/i5 CPU.